# Print Drupal 8 Menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-theming, drupal-templates, drupal-8

Does anyone have any idea how to print a menu in Drupal 8?

I've been trying to get it with something like {{ menu_primary }} but that doesn't work. I have several custom menus that I basically can't get on a page.

Answer (score 3):

If I am understanding this correctly, the best way to do this would be to print a region in your theme and then place the menu via the block interface into that region. This would reduce any custom coding dependency to your menu and allow your theme to focus on the region layout it provides to your content (including menus).

Here is a link to the docs explaining how to properly setup regions in a D8 theme: 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2469113

I hope that helps!

Have fun,

Nick

Answer (score 1):

if you have using bootstrap css and want print sub menu this done easily.hope this useful for you.
https://knackforge.com/blog/pathirakaliappan/create-multi-level-bootstrap-menu-in-Drupal-8

Comment: in this tutorial change your css  according your requirements

Comment: Please provide context for the link you are sharing. Although the link you shared may indeed be very helpful, it is advisable to rather capture the key aspects of the shared article that respond to the question. 
This way, even if the link is removed your answer will still be relevant and helpful.